# Safari won’t open on macbook air

Tags: safari

I go to open safari and it’ll act like it opens, but an actual web page doesn’t pop up. I’ve tried restarting the computer, force quitting safari, messing with the preferences and extend, and basically anything online offers as a solution.

Comment: What does `Activity Monitor` (`/Applications/Utilities`) show? Is Safari listed in the table of processes? Does it show up in red text with the words "Not responding" after it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. When you start Safari, does the first item in the menu bar at the top of the screen (next to the Apple symbol) read "Safari"? If that's the case, if you press Command-N, does a window open?